# Angular - Remove the CSS :hover behavior for mat-tab that is disabled

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I use hover effect to style `mat-tab`s in the project, but now I need to remove the mouse hover effect on `mat-tab`s that is `disabled`. Please let me know how to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
 <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="this.sortorder">
        <mat-tab #tab [disabled]='!tab.isActive' id="status"
                 *ngFor="let s of uppdragService.uppdragsStatusTyper | async" label="{{s.name}}"></mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .mat-tab-label{
      border: 1px solid black; 
      border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
      background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
      color: black;
      margin-left: 5px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .mat-tab-label:hover{
      background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
     
    }
    
    .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
      color: white;
      background-color: #003366;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Using this:
`.mat-tab-label:hover:enabled {background-color: rgb(206, 206,  206);}`

instead of:  `.mat-tab-label:hover{ background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);}` dosen't work with angulars `[disable]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like material adds a class `.mat-tab-disabled` when the tab is disabled. You can target it like this:

```
.mat-tab-label:hover:not(.mat-tab-disabled) {
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206); 
}
```

Comment: This dosen't work with angulars `[disable]`, I have already tried it before posting this..

Comment: @FilipHuhta updated my answer, try this and let me know if it works